# Removing non-matching dates from two time series in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have two time series x and y which roughly cover the same period of time. The data is in daily form however there are some days that have data in one dataset but no data in the other. I wish to use matlab to create two data-sets of equal size with matching dates. Essentially I wish to remove the days that don't have data in both x and y. Is there a simple way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: maybe you can traverse one time series (say x) with ismember() function applied on the other (say y)

Answer (score 1):

You could use an inner join see `help join` if you are able to convert your timeseries into datasets. If not you could use the ismember function, but this time you should do it only on the dates.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work:

```
a = {'2015-01-01', '2015-02-02', '2015-03-03'};
b = {'2015-01-01', '2015-03-03', '2015-04-04'};

newA = a(ismember(a,b));
newB = b(ismember(b,a));
```